# How to get all folder name in a folder on remote system?

Tags: c#

I like to know how to access all folder names inside a folder in remote system. I have a remote system called 'x'. Their is any way to access all folder in C:\oracle\oradata folder which is in remote system x? I am using c#.

Comment: please share your findings and tried code so that we can help you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes , but i am confused in how to set network path to connect with remote system.

Comment: You can use WMI query to get folders name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser.com, but anyway.

If you're using SMB (i.e. Windows File Sharing), then each volume (disk drive) on a computer is exposed as an "Administrative Share", which is the drive-letter followed by the `$` symbol. These shares have permissions on them that only allow members of the local Administrators group access.

The paths are simple, so to access your example, it's: `\\x\\C$\Oracle\Oradata\`

These paths work from within C# too:

```
DirectoryInfo share = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\x\\C$\Oracle\Oradata\");

foreach(DirectoryInfo child in share.GetDirectories()) {
    Console.WriteLine( child.FullName );
}
```

Comment: Directory.EnumerateDirectories would be more appropriate!